# mat-dialog-box not working as intended when used in another method angular

Tags: angular

i have tried to implement material dialog box which calls a confirmation box when yes/cancel is pressed it returns a boolean value which is passed to the method's (let's say) status value that checks if true or false where when true ,will continue to call the function's apiservice to load the data from the back-end.....I've already tried some but when called to a method, the method proceeds to run, but method runs before the dialog box even opens and returns false.......I apologize if i said anything wrong because i'm new to programming
Here are the two links iv'e followed but got the same problem
[Link1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example?file=app%2Fconfirmation-dialog.html),
[Link2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reusable-confirmation-dialog-angular-material?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-material%2Fcustom-material.module.ts)

Let's say this my code.

```
    normLoadMethod(param1,param2...){
      let status=false;
      if(param1=="actionname"){
       callDialogConfirm();
       status=this.resultOfDiagConfirm;//returns true/false
       }
       if(status==true){
       .....//method stuff
       this.apiservice.callDatafromBend(param1,param2).subscribe(result=>){
       //toastr notification the says success/failure
}}
    }



    callDialogConfirm(){
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogCommissionButtonDialog, {
          data:{//just the messagetitle and message confirm data}
       });
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((confirmed: boolean) => {
if (confirmed) {
   this.resultOfDiagConfirm=true
}else{
   this.resultOfDiagConfirm=false;
}//followed by other methods which are pretty much the same as link 1
```

Comment: I am a bit confused, the examples you gave, works without any bug right?. if the confirmation is true the method doesn't execute?

Comment: Lets say when it is called from another method ,it runs well for the first time,when called thew second time ,it dosent return anything from matDialogRef.afterClose.subscribe but gets called when the method is called the third time.....don't get it why its working like that though